# Does COM's put_XXX methods change to set_XXX in a .NET RCW

Tags: com, wrapper, rcw

I have a COM component that has get_XXX and put_XXX methods inside it. I used it in a .NET project and a RCW was generated for it. I now see get_XXX and set_XXX methods and NOT the put_XXX one? Is that automatic or defined somewhere in IDL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are property accessor methods.  A compiler that uses the COM server is expected to generate a call to get_Xxx() when the client program reads the property, put_Xxx() when it writes it.  A special one that C# doesn't have at all is putref_Xxx(), used to unambiguously access an object instead of a value.

The normal translation performed by Tlbimp.exe is as a plain C# property.  But that doesn't always work, C# is a lot more strict about what a property can look like:

- The default property, the one that's annotated as DISPID_VALUE (dispid 0) *must* take a single argument to be compatible.  This maps to the [C# indexer property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx), the one that makes it look like you are indexing an array.
- Any other property cannot take an argument, C# does not supported indexed properties other than the indexer.
- C# does not have the equivalent of putref_Xxx(), the syntax ambiguity cannot occur in a C# program because of the previous two bullets.  And the core reason that the C# team decided to put these restrictions in place, they greatly disliked ambiguity in the language.

So Tlbimp.exe is forced to deal with these restrictions, if the COM property accessors are not compatible then it *must* fall back to exposing them as plain methods instead of a property.  With default names, they'll get the `get_` and `set_` prefixes.  The latter one explains your question, they didn't pick `put_` for an otherwise unclear reason.

Notable is that C# version 4 relaxed several of these restrictions, most of all to make interop with Office programs easier.  Which was quite painful in earlier C# versions, to put it mildly.  It extended the property syntax to lessen the pain, but only for COM interop.  Very strongly recommended if you are still stuck on an old version of .NET, now is a good time to consider updating.

Comment: Is it possible to see this transformation somewhere in the interop assembly? Actually even in ILSpy decompiled code for interop dll, I see set_Xxx being called and not put_Xxx.

Comment: A COM method is not located by name at runtime.  It is simply an address in the interface dispatch table that the COM server provides.  No, you can't see it beyond looking at the machine code.

Answer (score 3):

The properties themselves have to prefixes (`put_` etc.), they have names, getter method, setter method, but no prefixes. Method table generated from type library receives prefixes to distinguish between getters and setters, hence the prefixes. Prefix string exactly depends on preference of the one who generates the names.

See also:

- `#pragma` `import` attributes - [`raw_property_prefixes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/621bz617.aspx)

> By default, low-level propget, propput, and propputref methods are exposed by member functions named with prefixes of get_, put_, and putref_ respectively. These prefixes are compatible with the names used in the header files generated by MIDL.

Comment: So that means .NET RCW automatically implements a set_XXX for COM control's put_XXX. Is this documented somewhere? Any links? I opened the interop dll in ILSpy thinking that the set_XXX method might be calling put_XXX internally but cannot find any reference.

Comment: Not this means a different thing: .NET RCW and COM refer to the same thing under different names. There is no need for name match there.